# How to share buildVariant cross not related modules with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-module

I have an Android app with two android modules (data and domain), following this arch

### App (Presentation) -> Domain <- Data

It means that **app** and **data** have a **domain** dependency (therefore app and data don't have a dependency between themselves)

I would like when **app** Build Type is selected, it automatically select the same build type in **data** module. Android studio should have the followed behaviour:

```
|Module| Build Variant
------------------------------
|app   | env1Debug
|domain| debug
|data  | env1Debug (automatically selected by app build type)
```

How can I share a buildVariant between not related modules?